# jquery select class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div id='divid'>
  <img class='showimg' src='..' />
  <img class='hideimg' src='..' style='display:none;' />
</div>
```

And I want to select the image inside the div with class 'showimg'.

I have tried `$(#divid.showimg)` but that doesnt seem to work..
How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a space between the ID and class, otherwise you are trying to select elements with *both* the ID and the class:

```
$('#divid .showimg')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('#divid .showimg')
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `$('#divid .showimg')` will not use `.find()` in any modern browser, it'll use `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: I always thought `find()` was slower.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I must check it out again. Thanks for the comment :)